# Getting a number of online users with meteor-presence

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to simply display a number of online users (currently logged in) with [meteor-presence](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-presence)?
I see that documents in `Meteor.presences` collection do not delete themselves by default, so simple `Meteor.presences.find().count()` is not the value I'm looking for... Should I delete them manually or should I check if each document has `userID` field somehow?

EDIT:
To illustrate a bit more what is happening to me, I tried to log in with 2 different users in 2 different browsers. After calling `Meteor.presences` I can see two documents in my collection, e.g.

```
docs: {
  djF3noxe3AhxDRfZw: {
    _id: "djF3noxe3AhxDRfZw",
    state: "online",
    userId: "SDeLPJzoabFt4Knei"
  }, {
  t4r2Q7KGKji4FPS9s: {
    _id: "t4r2Q7KGKji4FPS9s",
    state: "online",
    userId: "5zvYoC37aXSADGNEg"
  }
}
```

After few minutes of inactivity, both docs look the same. After logging out (calling `Meteor.logout()`) with one user I still have 2 documents (even after few minutes), the only difference is that one of them has no more `userID`:

```
docs: {
  djF3noxe3AhxDRfZw: {
    _id: "djF3noxe3AhxDRfZw",
    state: "online"
  }, {
  t4r2Q7KGKji4FPS9s: {
    _id: "t4r2Q7KGKji4FPS9s",
    state: "online",
    userId: "5zvYoC37aXSADGNEg"
  }
}
```

Only after closing that browser window the associated document deletes itself.
So, if I call `Meteor.presences.find().count()` when both windows are opened, I always get `2` in return, no matter of user's online/offline status.

All the code I am using at the moment is the one from the example:

```
Meteor.publish('userPresence', function() {
  var filter = {}; 
  return Meteor.presences.find(filter, {fields: {state: true, userId: true}});
});
```

Comment: I was seeing the same thing and it confused me as well. But when you think about it, a visitor looking at the page is a presence as well, yet doesn't have a userId. So it makes sense that any visitor would show up in the collection.

If you only want to see logged in users you could change filter to

var filter = {userId: {$exists: true}};

Comment: Hm, yeah, seems that this filter did the trick =) Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was seeing the same thing and it confused me as well. But when you think about it, a visitor looking at the page is a presence as well, yet doesn't have a userId. So it makes sense that any visitor would show up in the collection.

If you only want to see logged in users you could change filter to

```
var filter = {userId: {$exists: true}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with the package I've created, https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status. It doesn't double-count users, and you can just display or publish the value

```
Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true }).count()
```

It also updates immediately when users disconnect or log off.

Answer (score 0):

The documents delete themselves after a timeout period (10 seconds). https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-presence/blob/master/presence_server.js#L1

Comment: Thanks for answer avital! I did read that part about the browser activity and that doc should delete itself, but that is not happening to me. I edited my question with a bit more explanation. Maybe I'm missing something basically here but really not sure why since I'm not doing any magical stuff with my collections or the library itself :)